# How to make the angularJS pretty URL work directly in the browser?

Tags: angularjs

I have configured my AngularJS website to do HTML5 pretty URLs. I have done the 2 steps suggested

1. have set the HTML5 mode to true

```html
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/privacy', {
    templateUrl: 'html/privacy.html',
    controller: 'privacyController'
  });
    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    
}])
```

2. I have also set the base URL to "/".

It is working fine ( showing pretty URLs without the hash ) when I click any link on the website.

**Problem :** When I visit the link directly in the browser, it is not working. Is this even possible without a server side hack in Angular JS 1.0 ?

Comment: You have to implement URL Rewriting https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: It's not a server side hack, it's just normal configuration  to point all requests to your app.

Comment: Which exact version of angular are you using?

Comment: If you visit a different url, it won't load your AngularJS website at all. You have to tell the server that it should serve your website even if you don't visit its url directly.